# Interceptor and redirect with Alexa Skills

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

1. Can an interceptor be assigned to one intent only?
2. Can I redirect an interceptor to another intent?

I created a respose interceptor that check if user won the game and redirect from interceptor to another intent. The APL template of intent before interceptor is displayed but the audio that alexa speak is from the intent i redirected. And the APL template of redirected intent is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

> Can an interceptor be assigned to one intent only?

Yes you can, you need to use the same logic as the function `canHandle` within your interceptor:

```
canHandle(handlerInput: Alexa.HandlerInput) {
    // reuse this code
    return (
      Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === "IntentRequest" &&
      Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === "HelloWorldIntent"
    );
  },
```

> Can I redirect an interceptor to another intent?

Not exactly but you can do it differently. An interceptor does not reply to the request. It just `intercept the request` so your Intent can handle it. The `intent` is replying to request.

So you can put the logic on the session in the interceptor and the intent will know if the user has won the game or not.

**Interceptor**

```
const MyAwesomeInterceptor = {
  process(handlerInput) {
    const { attributesManager, requestEnvelope } = handlerInput;
    const sessionAttributes = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();

    // Code logic ...

    sessionAttributes.hasWon = true
  }
}
```

**Intent**

```
const HelloWorldIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return (
      Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === "IntentRequest" &&
      Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === "HelloWorldIntent"
    );
  },

  handle(handlerInput) {
    const { attributesManager } = handlerInput;
    const sessionAttributes = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();

    if (sessionAttributes.hasWon) {
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak("You won").getResponse();
    } else {
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak("You lost").getResponse();
    }
  },
};
```

I recommend you to check the [doc](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/ask-overviews/what-is-the-alexa-skills-kit.html) to have a better understanding on how Alexa work.

Comment: thank you....expected to be something similar to angular where you can assign interceptor just for some requests. I will be looking the doc .....